# MVC Unable to Find Undefined Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Looking at my logging records, I found a mass of exception stating that "Unable to Find Undefined Controller".

How could this happen? 
Is there anybody faced this problem before?
Is there anyway to fix it or at least ignore it?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like something is `undefined` in javascript and is hitting your MVC app.

For example

```
var url = 'http://myhost.com/';
url += desiredController;
$.ajax( /* .... */ );
```

If `desiredController` is `undefined`, and this call gets sent, I suspect MVC will be looking for `UndefinedController`.